# Converting int to currency format

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, int, currency, data-formats

guys. I would like to ask if there's anyway to make an int input to currency format? I have tried using

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
```

but, it would show an empty

> @Html.EditorFor

And if I used

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
```

It would only show 0.00

What I would like is when I input 10000, it would automatically format to

> Rp. 10.000

inside the @Html.EditorFor field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. "C" or "c" Currency Result:

   `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }`

**OR**

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
```

2. "N" or "n" Number Result:

   `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }`
3. In **Entity Framework**

`[DataType(DataType.Currency)] 
public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }`

**EditorTemplates Example:**

Create a editor template for currency `(~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Currency.cshtml)`:

**Currency.cshtml**

```
@Html.TextBox("", string.Format("{0:c}", ViewData.Model),new { @class = "text-box single-line" })
```

**Use:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalAmount, "Currency")
```

you can get more information form [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/extending-editor-templates-for-asp.net-mvc/) link.

Comment: does it require decimal as its model? because, it will have to make me change all of my model and database because they request to use int as the value model..

Comment: I think 3 no. option (`[DataType(DataType.Currency)]`) best if you use **Entity Framework**.@SionChristian

Comment: I'm not certain of what I'm using. I'm helping my University's IT Department on a development of a website. It IS connected to database. But, how they bind it, I'm not sure..

Comment: I test option 3 and i `use Entity Framework 6`.It's work for me .you can use a editortemplate for formating.@SionChristian

Comment: I update my answer and add **EditorTemplates**.@SionChristian

Comment: Thanks, @Ashiquzzaman. I haven't got the time to test it since they think it's wasting time, but you're very helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Html.Raw(@String.Format("{0:c}", @Model.YourFieldName))
```

Posting this because I couldn't find this answer anywhere.  This ended up working for me.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you could go into detail about why this is a solution.